# From dtype unique number to data type class

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

The numpy.dtype class allows to get a unique number that identify the datatypes among the existing 21.

https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.num.html#numpy.dtype.num

Is there a way to do the opposite? Giving the number to get the numpy class.

example:

```py
d_class = numpy.some_awesome_method(7)
print (d_class)
```

output:

```
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use this number?  I've answered quite a few `numpy` questions and I wasn't even aware of this `num` attribute.  We don't normally use such numbers.

Comment: @hpaulj In some operators definitions of ONNX format they use this number to inform about the data type. Digging I found that exists a helper **onnx.numpy_helper** that defines a method _to\_array()_ which does the conversion for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here looking for datatypes in ONNX format maybe you'd find useful the helper **onnx.numpy_helper**.